# import resolving error under core folder in main project

Tags: playn

I've been trying to get my code working with playn over the past few days. I'm getting some trouble enderstanding the how projects link to each other so I hope you can answer my question.

I imported a java project into the projectName-core project created by the eclipse maven template then resolved compilation error and everything is running fine when launching the java version of the game (using projectNamejava.java in the projectName-java folder).

My problem occurs when i try to compile it to html using google-> gwt compile. It tells me there are errors in the core folder of the project, and indeed there are many error in :
ProjectName/core
These errors are all due to unresolved import and when i try to fix them it says that the source is not linked to a project (not in the build path of any project).

So my questions are : 
how is the code in projectname-core linked to other projects? especially the "main project" (the one without postfix).
What can I do to resolve the error I get in the core folder of the main project?
Is there anything special to do to compile from java to html?

Thanks a lot for your time .

Cheers

Hush

EDIT : I solved the problem the hard way, erasing the project and making a new one with the same code worked (yet cleaning did not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem the hard way, erasing the project and making a new one with the same code worked (yet cleaning did not).